# changing macports install directory *after* installing

Tags: macports

I have macports installed on one computer, and I was hoping to just copy the entire /opt tree to another computer. Except, on the new computer (both are Intel Macs with Lion, so I am hoping to avoid recompiling all the packages) I have an extra hard disk, so I want to install macports on /Volumes/extradrive/opt

Can I copy the macports tree over from the old computer to the new computer and then change the directory path somewhere? I am guessing not, because all the software has been compiled expecting /opt. If so, can I recreate the entire macports on the new computer easily?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to maintain a single MacPorts `/opt` directory on two machines and have one installation outside of `/opt`, if they are both running the same version of OSX and XCode.  The quick and dirty way that I do the same task on my own machines is:

```
rsync -arvz $macports_host_machine:/opt/ /Volumes/extradrive/opt/
```

where `$macports_host_machine` is the machine on which MacPorts is installed (in `/opt/`).  Now, link `/Volumes/extradrive/opt` to `/opt`:

```
sudo ln -s /Volumes/extradrive/opt/ /opt/
```

I also perform this additional step

```
sudo chown -h username:group /opt
sudo chmod -h 755 /opt
```

to change ownership and permissions of the symbolic link.

After that, I maintain the `/opt` directory on only `$macports_host_machine` and rsync with all of my other machines (running the same version of OSX and XCode) periodically.

The previous instructions were written assuming that MacPorts was installed in `/opt` on `$macports_host_machine`, if MacPorts was installed in some other non-standard location, you should replace `/opt` with whatever the installation path is on `$macports_host_machine`